# vs2013 azure cloud service project fails to add a role

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-sdk-.net

I'm having troubles with VS 2013 and Azure SDK 2.2 respectively.

I've created an empty Cloud Service.

When I add a new Web Role (or Worker Role — it ends the same way) the new project starts being created, but the process fails with dialog message

```
Windows Azure Tools For Visual Studio
The following Nuget packages could not be installed in project 'projectname':
WindowsAzure.Storage (version '2.1.0.0'): One or more errors occured.
```

After pressing OK i get another dialog containing a NullReferenceException message

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

and after that end up with inconsistent content of the ServiceConfiguration and ServiceDefinition files: some of them contain mentions of the half-created project, others do not contain.

So, it is impossible for me now to create any Web or Worker roles. Does anyone have any ideas how to cope with it?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be the broken installation.

After uninstalling Azure SDK and VS 2013, and installing both again, the issue vanished.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem (with VS 2015). I was able to get rid of it by installing the Azure SDK from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/?sdk=net). I´m pretty sure I installed the SDK before from Visual Studio. But after installing the one from the link it worked.

Hope this helps if someone else has the same problem.